# airport extreme can't see usb drive

Tags: hard-drive, wifi, time-machine, usb, airport

I have the ac version of the airport extreme.  I have formatted my 8TB seagate drive to Mac OSX Extended (Journaled) several times and repaired it.  The Mac immediately asks me if I want to use it for time machine but the airport cannot see it.  It is a powered drive.  The drive has its own proprietary USB 3.0 cable.  I have successfully used it with an airport extreme (ac) before.  Additionally, I have tried putting a powered USB hub between it and the airport.  How do I fix this?

Comment: Do you have a spare USB drive you could test on the AirPort? That could help us figure out the issue.

Comment: Excellent idea.  The USB drive doesn't work either.

Comment: Ok then, I reckon that it's a problem with the AirPort then, if both of these drives work when not connected to the AirPort. Has the 8TB drive been reformatted ever since it was on the old Airport Extreme?

Comment: I've reformatted / repaired it several times as a part of the troubleshooting process.  I'm ponying up and buying a certified refurbished airport.  Hopefully that works.

Comment: Ok, good idea. DO Apple still sell refurbed items?

Comment: I don't think so... amazon does: https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B013PUNMBU/